# NameScope.SetNameScope Not found

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Hi iam trying to use de  NameScope.SetNameScope to start an animation in a xaml for a Silverligth application, but it seems like the visual studio does not recognise the  NameScope.SetNameScope, why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Silverlight doesn't support the NameScope class.

Silverlight is a significantly reduced sub-set of the full .NET API plus some Silverlight specific API.